# OnSubmit data validation w/ invalid fields and correct data return

Tags: javascript, html, css, validation, field

I am having trouble with a lab of mine and just need some guidance or tips on where to go.
I need a function that alerts the user when any field is invalid and red outline any section that is invalid and if no sections are valid then to instead just display the users input such as name, gender state, fav movie type and so on.

I am stumped because I have created a test function which does not even work correctly when the user selects submit. when the name field is left empty it does not even alert the user that left the field blank.

```
    <html>
<head>
<title>Form Practice</title>

</head>


<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
///// validate names


const form = document.getElementById("form");
document.getElementById("form").addEventListener("submit", validate);

var myForms=document.getElementById("myForms")
function validate(e) {
   var first= document.forms["myForm"]["firstName"].value;
   if(first==""){
    alert("enter the first name");
    event.preventDefault()
    firstName.style.borderColor="red";
    event.preventDefault()
    return false;
    }
    }





</script>
<h1>Please Provide the Following Information</h1>
*fields marked with an asterisk are required<br><br>


<form name="myForm"  id="form" method="post" action="mailto:lasdfasdf@asdfas.com" >


First Name*: <input type="text" name="firstName"><br>
Last Name*: <input type="text" name="lastName"><br>
Gender*: <input type="radio" name="gender" value="M">Male  
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="F">Female <br>


Choose Your Favorite Types of Movies (check all that applies):
<input type="checkbox" name="movies" value="comedy"> Comedy
<input type="checkbox" name="movies" value="drama"> Drama
<input type="checkbox" name="movies" value="action"> Action
<input type="checkbox" name="movies" value="horror"> Horror<br>


Please select your state:  
<select name="state">
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
    <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
    <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
    <option value="CA">California</option>
    <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
    <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
    <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
    <option value="DC">District Of Columbia</option>
    <option value="FL">Florida</option>
    <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
    <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
    <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
    <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
    <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
    <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
    <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
    <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
    <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
    <option value="ME">Maine</option>
    <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
    <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
    <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
    <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
    <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
    <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
    <option value="MT">Montana</option>
    <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
    <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
    <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
    <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
    <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
    <option value="NY">New York</option>
    <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
    <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
    <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
    <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
    <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
    <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
    <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
    <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
    <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
    <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
    <option value="TX">Texas</option>
    <option value="UT">Utah</option>
    <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
    <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
    <option value="WA">Washington</option>
    <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
    <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
    <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>   <br>        
Agree to privacy policy* <input type="checkbox" name="privacy"  value="yes"> <br><br>
<input type="submit">
<input type="reset">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `or` operator to check if first or last name is empty, also you need `event.preventDefault()` to cancel default action

```js
function ValidationEvent(e) {
    var fname = document.myForm.firstName;
    var lname = document.myForm.lastName;
    if (!fname.value || !lname.value) { // use 'or' operator here 
        fname.classList.add('red-border');
        lname.classList.add('red-border');
        e.preventDefault(); // Cancel action
        alert("fill out please.");
    }
    else {
        alert("thank you");
    }
}
```

```html
<h1>Please Provide the Following Information</h1>
*fields marked with an asterisk are required<br><br>
<form name="myForm" method="post" action="mailto:lasdfasdf@asdfas.com" 

onsubmit="ValidationEvent(event)"> <!-- ValidationEvent(event) is required -->

  First Name*: <input type="text" name="firstName"><br>
  Last Name*: <input type="text" name="lastName"><br>
  Gender*: <input type="radio" name="gender" value="M">Male
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="F">Female <br>

  Choose Your Favorite Types of Movies (check all that applies):
  <input type="checkbox" name="movies" value="comedy"> Comedy
  <input type="checkbox" name="movies" value="drama"> Drama
  <input type="checkbox" name="movies" value="action"> Action
  <input type="checkbox" name="movies" value="horror"> Horror<br>

  Please select your state:
  <select name="state">
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>

  </select> <br>
  Agree to privacy policy* <input type="checkbox" name="privacy" value="yes"> <br><br>
  <input type="submit">
  <input type="reset">
</form>
```

Comment: https://gist.github.com/ZechCodes/74c5db47f3ea1cbd4ead2c0134a4b50f    so I was able to create a list of var and if statements but how would I write so that when the user hits submit everything will be validated at once and all invalid areas including radio,select,check would be marked with a red border.

Comment: you can set attribute `required` to the elements, [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u2qkocv0/)

Answer (score 0):

What you are struggling with is that you are using the htmlinput whole dom element instead of the value of it, when in doubt always print the value and check what it actually contains `console.log(fname);`. So in your case you need to access the value of it, which you can get from the console.log actually. `document.myForm.firstName.value`

I added a small beginning for the red thingy you asked on the input but left the rest to you so i dont spoil the fun of it.

Here is a working jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/odsvpwf0/

Comment: @Tahot https://gist.github.com/ZechCodes/74c5db47f3ea1cbd4ead2c0134a4b50f   I think I got it somewhat but how would one validate everything at one time and redline every single item when the user hits submit